# Find an example of a continuous function and open (closed) A such that f(A) is not open(closed)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

for a continuous function and open A such that f(A) is not open. I think $f:R \rightarrow R$, and $f(A)=0 $ for $A \in (0,1)$ works. since a singe point in $R$ is closed.

I have no idea to find a continuous function and closed A such that f(A) is not closed.

Comment: just an example

Comment: If you are restricting yourself to functions $f:R\to R$, then $A$ must be a non-compact closed set. (Think about why this must be so.)

Comment: Kind of confusing that the question ends with (closed), since [closed] has meaning on SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$ and $A= \mathbb{R}$.

Then $f(\mathbb{R}) = (0,1]$ which is neither open nor closed.
$A$ is both open and closed.

Comment: why you put the -ve sign in the power of e?

Comment: Now thanks I understood why.